# Sort date and time values

Tags: java, sorting, date, time, timestamp

Putting simply, I have a string array of different dates and times. Each element is of this format:

> 2015-08-27T22:24:31.903

That is, YYYY-MM-DD**T**HH:MM:SS.MMM

I'm sorting them. Is there a default method available to sort this format?

What I'm doing now is splitting the string at **T**, converting the date and time to respective timestamps, adding them and then sorting the timestamp values. Is there a direct parser for this format available? A better solution is most-welcome.

Comment: You can simply sort the Strings, because they are in the [ISO-8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#General_principles) format which makes them easily sortable. No conversion is needed.

Comment: Don’t keep your dates and times as strings. Just like you don’t keep your numbers as strings (I hope!) Keep proper date-time objects like `LocalDateTime` (from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/)). Such implement `Comparable`, that is, have a natural order agreeing with chronological order, so are easily sortable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I have a string array. Each element is of this format: `2015-08-27T22:24:31.903`. Is there a default method available to sort this format?

Yes. Since the ISO string has date fields in descending order of magnitude, and fields are fixed-width, you can simple sort the strings directly using [`Arrays.sort(Object[] a)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort-java.lang.Object:A-): *Sorts the specified array of objects into ascending order, according to the natural ordering of its elements.*

> Is there a direct parser for this format available?

Yes. [`LocalDateTime.parse(CharSequence text)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html#parse-java.lang.CharSequence-): *Obtains an instance of `LocalDateTime` from a text string such as `2007-12-03T10:15:30`.*

Comment: is this procedure can be used to sort time stamps in this format `2016-08-16T06:31:34Z`

Answer (score 4):

I take it those are strings. If you don't want to do the obvious (convert them to [`LocalDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDateTime.html)¹ and compare the result), you can just compare them as strings, that particular date-time format (a nearly-full ISO-8601 timestamp, just missing a timezone indicator) works correctly when you use string comparison.

Gratuitous example ([live copy](http://ideone.com/YOMvVC)):

```
import java.util.*;

class Example
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        String[] strings = {
            "2002-10-24T13:51:25.417",
            "2001-03-25T23:41:24.234",
            "2008-10-05T04:41:56.004",
            "2013-04-10T22:14:06.852",
            "2005-08-24T05:05:01.080",
            "2015-11-20T17:32:27.303",
            "2003-07-16T06:32:07.703",
            "2005-03-20T08:28:18.440",
            "2009-04-17T13:20:09.499",
            "2002-11-04T06:39:55.287"
        };
        Arrays.sort(strings);
        for (String s : strings) {
            System.out.println(s);
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
2001-03-25T23:41:24.234
2002-10-24T13:51:25.417
2002-11-04T06:39:55.287
2003-07-16T06:32:07.703
2005-03-20T08:28:18.440
2005-08-24T05:05:01.080
2008-10-05T04:41:56.004
2009-04-17T13:20:09.499
2013-04-10T22:14:06.852
2015-11-20T17:32:27.303
```

You can, of course, provide a `Comparator` if you need a different ordering (such as reverse order).

---

¹ or [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Instant.html), if these are actually UTC date/times, but you'd need to add a `Z` to the end of the strings before parsing.

Comment: Actually, you would convert those particular values to `java.time.LocalDateTime` rather than `Instant`.

Comment: @BasilBourque - Ah, yes, quite so -- `Instant` would want a `Z` on the string, which could be incorrect. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

## Using modern Java

The [Answer by Andreas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39700121/642706) is correct. Here is a variation using newer features added to later versions of Java.

Make some example data using [`List.of`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#of(E,E,E,E)). The resulting list is nonmodifiable. So feed the nonmodifiable list to the constructor of [`ArrayList`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/ArrayList.html) to get a modifiable list we can sort.

```
List < String > strings = new ArrayList <>(
        List.of(
                "2015-08-27T22:24:31.903" ,
                "2018-08-27T22:24:31.903" ,
                "2016-08-27T22:24:31.903" ,
                "2017-08-27T22:24:31.903"
        )
);
```

### Sort as text

As noted in that other Answer, your strings are in standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format. That particular format is designed to be chronological when sorted alphabetically. So, if this task is your only goal for this data, then you need not parse as date-time object. Just sort as text, as `String` objects.

Rather than using the [`Collections`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collections.html) utility class, the [`List`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#sort(java.util.Comparator)) interface has gained the [`sort`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#sort(java.util.Comparator)) method. That method demands a [`Comparator`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Comparator.html). Rather than implement that interface, we can call [`Comparator.naturalOrder()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Comparator.html#naturalOrder()) to produce an instance.

```
strings.sort( Comparator.naturalOrder() );
```

Dump to console.

```
System.out.println( "strings = " + strings );
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/komgI6).

> strings = [2015-08-27T22:24:31.903, 2016-08-27T22:24:31.903, 2017-08-27T22:24:31.903, 2018-08-27T22:24:31.903]

### Sort as date-time objects

If you will be further work with this input, then parse as date-time objects.

The modern approach uses *java.time* classes.

We can simplify our example data, as we can work directly with a nonmodifiable `List` produced by `List.of`.

```
List < String > strings =
        List.of(
                "2015-08-27T22:24:31.903" ,
                "2018-08-27T22:24:31.903" ,
                "2016-08-27T22:24:31.903" ,
                "2017-08-27T22:24:31.903"
        );
```

Make an empty `List` of [`LocalDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDateTime.html) objects.

```
List < LocalDateTime > ldts = new ArrayList <>( strings.size() );
```

Populate that list by parsing our input strings one at a time, producing a `LocalDateTime` object. Add that object to our list.

Notice that *java.time* classes use ISO 8601 formats by default. So no need to specify a formatting pattern.

```
for ( String string : strings )
{
    ldts.add( LocalDateTime.parse( string ) );  // Parsing text in ISO 8601 format needs no formatting pattern to be specified.
}
```

Sort, as we did above. Call `List::sort`, passing a `Comparator`.

```
ldts.sort( Comparator.naturalOrder() ) ;
```

See that [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/ncY7M5).

```
System.out.println( "ldts = " + ldts );
```

#### Streams

We can replace the `for` loop with a `Stream`, if we want to get fancy. We can do this work as a one-liner.

```
List < String > strings =
        List.of(
                "2015-08-27T22:24:31.903" ,
                "2018-08-27T22:24:31.903" ,
                "2016-08-27T22:24:31.903" ,
                "2017-08-27T22:24:31.903"
        );

List < LocalDateTime > ldts = 
    strings
    .stream()
    .map( s -> LocalDateTime.parse( s ) )
    .sorted()
    .collect( Collectors.toList() )
;

System.out.println( "ldts = " + ldts );
```

> ldts = [2015-08-27T22:24:31.903, 2016-08-27T22:24:31.903, 2017-08-27T22:24:31.903, 2018-08-27T22:24:31.903]

Answer (score 1):

1) Parse your strings using the appropriate SimpleDateFormat:

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.SSS");
try {
    Date date = formatter.parse(dateInString);
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

2) Store each date in a list. To do that firstly instantiate a new list...

```
ArrayList<Date> myDates = new ArrayList<Date>();
```

... after the parse command add each date to the list:

```
myDates.add(date);
```

3) Sort them using:

```
Collections.sort(myDates); // Ascending
```

or

```
Collections.sort(myDates, Collections.reverseOrder()); // Descending
```

Comment: No need to parse to `Date`, since string is sortable, as-is.

Answer (score 0):

**Sort with Date and Time using Calendar API**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;

public class SortMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ArrayList<SomeObj> al= new ArrayList();

        SomeObj s1 = new SomeObj("9", "2020-02-05");
        al.add(s1);
        s1 = new SomeObj("7", "2020-02-05");
        al.add(s1);
        /*s1 = new SomeObj("15", "2019-12-25");
        al.add(s1);
        s1 = new SomeObj("6", "2019-12-25");
        al.add(s1);*/

        printArrayList(al);

        Collections.sort(al);

        System.out.println("*************");

        printArrayList(al);

    }

    private static void printArrayList(ArrayList<SomeObj> al) {
        for(SomeObj someObj: al) {
            System.out.println(someObj.getDate() + " ** " + someObj.getTime());
        }
    }
}
```

And,

```
package com.karthik.sorting;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;

public class SomeObj implements Comparable<SomeObj>{

    private String time;
    private String date;

    public SomeObj(String time, String date) {
        super();
        this.time = time;
        this.date = date;
    }
    public String getTime() {
        return time;
    }
    public void setTime(String time) {
        this.time = time;
    }
    public String getDate() {
        return date;
    }
    public void setDate(String date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

     @Override
     public int compareTo(SomeObj siteHealthGraphItem) {
         String receivedPattern = "yyyy-MM-dd";
         SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(receivedPattern);
         try {
             Date date1 = simpleDateFormat.parse(getDate().toString());
             Date date2 = simpleDateFormat.parse(siteHealthGraphItem.getDate().toString());

             if (getTime() == null) {
                 return date1.compareTo(date2);
             } else if (getTime() != null) {

                 Calendar cal1 = Calendar.getInstance();
                 cal1.setTime(date1);
                 cal1.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, Integer.parseInt(getTime()));

                 Calendar cal2 = Calendar.getInstance();
                 cal2.setTime(date2);
                 cal2.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, Integer.parseInt(siteHealthGraphItem.getTime()));

                 return cal1.compareTo(cal2);
             }
         } catch (Exception e) {
             System.out.println("Data is improper - Sorting Did not work..!");
             e.printStackTrace();
         }
         System.out.println("Sorting Did not work..!");
         return 0;
     }


}
```

Comment: Please don’t teach the young ones to use the long outdated and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` class. At least not as the first option. And not without any reservation. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API,](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) and its `DateTimeFormatter`.