# Change datetime object into integer in html or jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I want to convert `datetime.now()` objects into integers.

For example:

```
2019-07-18 11:16:33.325366
```

should be converted to `yyyymmddhhmmss` format:

```
20190718111633
```

This is so that my column of dates can be properly sorted using `sorttable.js`.

How should I do that in html directly or by using jquery? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I think it should be sorted properly even it's in original format?

Comment: As @Chaska said, the format of "2019-07-18 11:16:33.325366" is already sortable.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sort date and time values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39699787/sort-date-and-time-values), although the format is not identical it can be sorted in the same way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [`toISOString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString) and `replace()`

```js
let date = new Date().toISOString().substr(0, 19).replace(/-|T|:/g, '')

console.log(date)
```

Answer (score 0):

Break your date and replace using RegEx like below.

```js
let d = new Date($.now());
let result = d.getFullYear() + " " + (d.getMonth()+1) + " " + d.getDate() + " " + d.getHours() + " " + d.getMinutes() + " " + d.getSeconds();
console.log(result.replace(/ /g, ""));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var date = new Date(); // M-D-YYYY

console.log(Date.parse(date));
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33804536)